# Better way to implement the following long running thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, while-loop

I have an application that has a main thread that waits for an event (receiving a file in the directory, for example) and Post that file to an API. This part is working fine.

On the other hand, due to some reasons, it's possible that the main thread misses out some files. So, I have setup a background thread to run throughout application lifetime cleaning up those missed files as shown below:

```
public virtual void MissedFileHandler()
{
     if (_missedFileHandlerThread == null || !_missedFileHandlerThread.IsAlive)
     {
          _missedFileHandlerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ClearMissedFiles));
          _missedFileHandlerThread.IsBackground = true;
          _missedFileHandlerThread.Start();
     }
}

protected virtual void ClearMissedFiles()
{
     while (true)
     {
         string[] missedFiles = new string[] { };
         missedFiles = Directory.GetFiles(ConfigurationHelper.applicationRootDirectory, "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
         Parallel.ForEach(missedFiless, (currentMissedFile) =>
         {
             bool isFileInUse = true;
             isFileInUse = FileHelper.CheckIfFileInUse(filesInUseCollection, currentMissedFile)
             if (!isFileInUse)
             {
                 bool isHttpTransferSuccess = false;
                 isHttpTransferSuccess = FileHelper.SendFileToApi(userid, currentMissedFile);
             if (isHttpTransferSuccess)
             {
                  File.Delete(currentMissedFile);

             }
         }
     });
     Thread.Sleep(1000);
     }
  }
```

Please note that running this as a Windows service or a scheduler is not an option for some other reasons. So, I do need a background worker to clean up missed files periodically. I checked out `Timer` and `WaitHandles` but not very sure how I can implement the following using those.

The way the two processes (main even handler for new files and the background cleaner is invoked are, in the main application thread I will instantiate the class and invoke the methods at application startup. It's the `Thread.Sleep()` and the `while (true)` that is bothering me and am looking for a better approach. Thanks.

Comment: Use a file watcher to detect new files in that directory.

Comment: If this background task is "capable" of doing the same job as the main thread, why are both of them doing this work? Why not leave it all to the background thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a file watcher to detect new files in that directory.

```
private void watch()
{
  FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

  // Set your path with this
  watcher.Path = path;

  // Subscribe to event
  watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
  watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this and see if it works for my use case. I may be able to completely avoid having to use two threads if this works reliably. Will accept as answer if this works.

Comment: The issue with this code will be responding to failure. Is the file in use? Was the HTTP transfer successful. This answer is a good start, but it's not a complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Microsoft's Reactive Framework. Then you can do this:

```
IObservable<Unit> fileChanges =
    Observable
        .Using(() =>
        {
            var fsw = new FileSystemWatcher();
            fsw.Path = path;
            fsw.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            return fsw;
        }, fsw =>
            Observable
                .FromEventPattern<FileSystemEventHandler, FileSystemEventArgs>(
                    h => fsw.Changed += h,
                    h => fsw.Changed -= h))
        .Select(ep => Unit.Default);

IObservable<Unit> periodically =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.0))
        .Select(x => Unit.Default);

IObservable<string> clearMissedFiles =
    fileChanges
        .Merge(periodically)
        .SelectMany(u => Directory.GetFiles(ConfigurationHelper.applicationRootDirectory, "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
        .Where(f => !FileHelper.CheckIfFileInUse(filesInUseCollection, f))
        .SelectMany(f => Observable.Start(() => FileHelper.SendFileToApi(userid, f)), (f, s) => new { file = f, success = s })
        .Where(x => x.success)
        .Select(x => x.file);

IDisposable subscription =
    clearMissedFiles
        .Subscribe(f => File.Delete(f));
```

This watches the file system and check periodically. And calls the API in parallel and it doesn't cause the O/S grief with trying to delete multiple files at once.

Just call `subscription.Dispose()` to clean up before exiting.

NuGet "System.Reactive" for the bits and then reference `using System.Reactive.Linq` for the extensions to show.